# How to Display Content Extraction from Links on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Improvised:** In order to show a user a summary of an arbitrary web page like the title, image and meta description, how can I retrieve meta data and images from a document based on its URL and that to when someone hovers over the embedded URL as a link in a post.

A hint of this type of effect : http://rap.genius.com/Casey-veggies-the-boy-lyrics

Comment: Why would you want to not use CSS? it is easier and works when scripts are not allowed.

Comment: if you not want to use html, how you want to display anything ? alerts ?

Comment: without css and html, js cannot magic a popup.

Comment: @ImagineStudios adding manually this interaction to thousands of pages would be a hectic job so I thought scripts will be very helpful for the all round interaction.

Comment: so the thing is, you dont know anything about html and css ? and you want to save you the work learning it ?

Comment: @Dwza I mean not manually having to change or add anything in HTML

Comment: it's not like you will add code for each of the elements

Comment: actually you cant display anything without html. so even if you do it in js, you will put some html in your script....only way is a alert and there you cant really design it (at least the original alert)

Comment: @doniyor I know I just don't want to add or change HTML manually but I scripts can do that

Comment: would this be for pages on your site, or pages anywhere out there?

Comment: @Geniusknight you dont add htmls manuelly, but you should create html manuelly once and show it everytime if you hover on target element.

Comment: @doniyor oh so we can't extract things like this using javascript or php

Comment: @Geniusknight look at this. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers  you can change the event handler to hover.

Comment: @dandavis pages for my site and I guess it should also work for external links like giving a short preview of linked article's image, title and meta description

Comment: @Geniusknight here how it goes: i hope, you know how ajax works. on hover event, call ajax method which tries to curl the link and get those informations and returns you back. you catch those informations and render them into popup html and call the ``show_popup()``

Comment: @doniyor oh so it's done with Ajax ! I saw this effect here http://rap.genius.com/Casey-veggies-the-boy-lyrics and wanted to show it for my linked articles as well on my site.

Comment: Of course you can add content to a page without writing HTML.  Use dom manipulation methods: `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));`  No HTML, but new div element created in the current document.

Comment: @gilly3 I know we can add content using Scripts but I want to know how to extract content from links such as it's title, image and meta description

Comment: What do you mean by "link"?  I usually think of a link as just an anchor element.  It sounds like you want to extract content from the **document** that a link points to, rather than from the link itself.

Comment: @gilly3 yes exactly !

Comment: For the image, are you looking for an image *of* the web page (like a screenshot) or an image *from* the web page (the way facebook shows link previews by grabbing an image from the linked page)?

Comment: Yes exactly @gilly3 something like that ! Actually the idea popped up while reading Open graph meta tags and this site http://rap.genius.com/Casey-veggies-the-boy-lyrics try hovering on produced by links

Comment: I've voted to close your question as unclear what you are asking. Based on your comments, it sounds like you know how to create a popup with JavaScript, but you don't know how to access the data for populating such a popup.  Please edit this question to remove everything that you already know how to do.  I would expect your revised question to read something like, "In order to show a user a summary of an arbitrary web page, how can I retrieve meta data and images from a document based on its URL?"  Once you make those edits, I'll retract my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this client side because of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) restrictions.  You'll need server side code to do most of the work.  Create a handler in the server side language of your choice that takes a URL, requests it server-side, parses the response, and extracts the desired information from the parsed document, and returns JSON.  You can use something like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to do the document parsing on the server.

Then, it would just be a matter of calling that page from your code:

```
$("a[href^=http]").hover(function(e) {
    var url = encodeURIComponent(this.href);
    $.get("/summary?url=" + url, function(summary) {
        // use data from summary to create popup
    });
}, function(e) {
    // hide popup
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create your link detail element when you hover into a link and remove it again when you hover out.  You don't need to add the popup content to the actual DOM.  You will probably want to have the CSS for the popup, though this too can be set when you create the element in JS.

JS to add the link detail popup:

```
  $('.hoverLink').hover(
    function(){
      var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
      var myTitle = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).append('<div class="hoverDetail"><p>HREF: ' + myHref+ '</p><p>TITLE: ' + myTitle + '</div>');
    }, 
    function(){
      $('.hoverDetail').remove();
    });
```

CSS to make the popup display under the link

```
.hoverLink {
  position: relative;
}

.hoverDetail {
    border: 4px solid #eee;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    background: white;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fl1PkASx4gPro8hKGR9Z?p=preview

Comment: have a look at here http://rap.genius.com/Casey-veggies-the-boy-lyrics hover over the links in produced by

Comment: I think the answer still holds.  The only difference is that they are extracting the info on click instead of hover and putting it into a div that has a static location on the page instead of hovering it.  Also, for what it is worth - they are not hand coding this, they are using the qTip pluggin: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Comment: Oooh I can totally use that ! Thanks for the awesomeness ! :D

Comment: Cool, I hope it helps you a bit. I did notice on the qTip page after posting that they no longer develop qTip, but have moved to http://qtip2.com/

Comment: Thanks I will use their wisdom ! :D

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to the whole post!**

According to your Link you posted:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E75H7/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //creates an info div. you could also add some style here. 
    //i added it seperatly in jsfiddle
    var div = $("<div class='info'></div>");

    //adds the info div to body
    //of course you can add it to any other element that you can select
    $('body').append(div);

    //add a hover effekt to all links. 
    //here you better use a class like e.g. .myHoverLinks
    $('a').hover(function(){

        //THIS PART IS CALLED ON MOUSEIN
        //set some content for infodiv and show it
        $(div).html('Mouse Hover. On out, window will hide. Hovering: ' + $(this).html()).show();

    },function(){

        //THIS PART IS CALLED ON MOUSEOUT
        //check if infodiv is hovered
        if($(div).is(":hover"))
        {
            //i added this to keep info alive as long as you hover it
            $(div).hover(function(){},function(){$(this).hide();});
        }
        else
        {
            //hides info if you leave with mouse in way up...
            $(div).hide();
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Hmm I don't wish to add content but extract it ! The script clearly has to add manually things again.

Comment: @Geniusknight this one should be the one like the link you posted